# Return to libc causes an segmentation fault

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I am trying to create a buffer overflow using return to libc.

Here is the attacker code:
http://codepad.org/TtoLjAHc . It creates the payload and stores it in a file named badfile.

Here is the vulnerable code:
http://codepad.org/DZ7AQy4D. It reads from badfile and is supposed to spawn a shell.

ASLR and stack-protection are off.

The attacker code works. But the vulnerable code causes a segfault.

Can anyone please explain where I am going wrong?

Relevant sections of exploiter code:

```
memset(buffer, "\x90", 52);
memcpy(buffer,"BUF=",4);
memcpy(buffer+36, systemAddr,4);
memcpy(buffer+40,exitAddr,4);
memcpy(buffer+44, shAddr,4);
memcpy(buffer+48, nullPad, 4);
```

This variable, buffer, is now written to a file named badfile, which is read by the vulnerable program using fread().
Relevant section of vulnerable program:

```
char buffer[12];
length = fread (buffer, sizeof (char), 52, badfile);
```

Comment: Please post the _relevant_ parts of the code inline here, as well as what you learnt by running your exploit in a debugger.

Comment: Mat,
Could you please take a look at the post now? I have put relevant sections of code as asked.
Thanks in advance,
Roy

Comment: Overrun exploits are very sensitive. You'll have to spend some time with a debugger, understand the stack layout, see where's the buffer, where's the return address, how much exactly you have overrun and what exactly happened. I don't think debugging via forum would work.

Answer (score -1):

You have allocated 12 octets of memory for `buffer`, but you try to write 52 octets. Therefore you go out of the array provoking the segmentation fault.

Try:

```
*char buffer[12];
length = fread (buffer, sizeof (char), **12**, badfile);*
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: That's intentional, it's a deliberate buffer overflow vulnerability that OP is trying to exploit.